# Only one column sorting using JQuery Table Sorter Plug-In

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sorting, gridview, tablesorter

I'm using jQuery's tablesorter plugin to sort my gridview on the client side. But here is the problem, i have to make that sorting option available to only one column. (column number is 7 in gridview)

```
 $("#<%=gvResults.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
```

How can we make it possible with table sorter plug-in. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the column index that will have sorting enabled, then set the `headers` option as follows:

```
$(function(){
  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
      // zero-based column index
      0 : { sorter: false },
      1 : { sorter: false },
      2 : { sorter: false },
      3 : { sorter: false },
      4 : { sorter: false },
      5 : { sorter: false }
    }
  });
});
```

The above code works on both the original tablesorter and my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html).

If you happen to be using my fork of tablesorter, then you can add class names to the headers:

```
<th class="sorter-false">column 1</th>
<th class="sorter-false">column 2</th>
<th class="sorter-false">column 3</th>
<!-- etc -->
<th>column 7</th>
```

and then initialize tablesorter without any extra options:

```
$(function(){
  $('table').tablesorter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the class 'header' from headers you don't want sortable, for example if its only the seventh row you want sortable, write

```
$('.header').not('.header:nth-child(7)').removeClass('header');
```

Run this on start by adding this html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.header').not('.header:nth-child(7)').removeClass('header');
        $('.header').not('.header:nth-child(7)').click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.headerSortDown').removeClass('headerSortDown');  // fixes a bug
        $('.headerSortUp').removeClass('headerSortUp');  // fixes a bug
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This code will only work *after* tablesorter (original version) has initialized.